# Source for comestible cracked corn

Tags: corn

Over the summer, I had the opportunity to have some cracked corn which is similar to pop corn but with a different species of corn that had bigger kernels and the chef that served them said they were starchier which meant that they popped differently, the texture was the same as the type of kernels that are at the bottom of a bag but only slightly popped.

I've had a hard time looking for a source except for cracked corn as animal feed which I wouldn't trust for my own consumption. Does anyone know of a place to find some to pop?

Comment: How was this prepared? Cracked corn would not pop as the steam could not build up to explode the kernel. Is it possible you had hominy? From http://www.thekitchn.com/h-is-for-hominy-what-is-it-and-100215 "These big kernels of corn are puffy and chewy with a very unique flavor owing to a special processing technique."

Comment: Dry, large kernel corn can usually be found in Latino grocery stores. It comes in white and purple. It's used as starting material for tortillas.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen them called "pop pops". NatureBox sells them:
https://naturebox.com/product/sea-salt-pop-pops

Trader Joe's has a variant:
[https://www.amazon.com/Trader-Joes-Partially-Popped-Popcorn/dp/B00WOQ31AY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WOQ31AY)

There's also a brand called "half pops" at halfpops.com.

Googling turned up a recipe for making them, but I haven't tried it:
http://www.jenosmon.com/blog/half-popped-popcorn/